# Making POST request to SQL Server through React

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs

I am trying to make a simple textbox entry form for the user to type their first and last name, then click submit. I'd like the data to be updated in my SQL Server. Whenever I try to make a request I get the error

> Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

This is the code I am using:

**server.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sql = require("mssql");

var config = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'Master' 
};

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    var user = req.body;
    var connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, function(err) {
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query('INSERT INTO Persons SET ?', user);
    });
    res.end('Success');
  });

app.listen(5000, () => {console.log('Server is running..')});
```

And here is the code from react:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class postData extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { user: {} };
        this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }
      handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;
        // On submit of the form, send a POST request with the data to the server.
        fetch('http://localhost:5000', { 
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
              FirstName: self.refs.FirstName,
              LastName: self.refs.LastName
            }
          })
         .then(function(response) {
            //this is the line that is giving me the error
            return response.json()
          }).then(function(body) {
            console.log(body);
          });
          }
      render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ref="FirstName"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ref="LastName"/>
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>
        );
      }
}

export default postData;
```

I am getting the error from the react side.  Not sure how to set this up. Any ideas where I might be screwing up? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you get that error because the response is a string instead of a JSON object. Try changing your express:

```
res.send({ message: 'Success'})
```

I'n not sure that you're using refs correctly either. I might try putting those values in state with an on change function:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState(
        {
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    )
}
```

And change your inputs to:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Then in your submit function:

```
FirstName: this.state.FirstName
```

Hope that helps

Comment: So that fixes the original error, however it won't post the data into my SQL table.  Does my query look correct?  In my SQL table I have a column called "FirstName" and a column called "LastName"

Comment: I'm not super familiar with SQL tables tbh. Are you getting any errors in the callback? Also, what does your `req.body` look like?

Comment: Right now I'm getting "Undefined".  I ran the code that @Robert Stefanic suggested, and it's definitely making a post to my table, just giving me undefined for those values.  I tried your suggestion above, but still getting undefined

Answer (score 1):

The data that your react app is passing to express is just the raw text. Try adding [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to your express app, and then deconstructing the values that are passed in. You could manually parse the body into JSON format, but it would be much easier to include body-parser. body-parser also allows you to parse the body of your request into other formats as well if you wish.

Add body-parser to your express app:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then in your POST request, deconstruct the body like like this:

```js
const { firstName, lastName } = req.body;
let connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, function(err) {
    let request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query(/* Your query to insert these values */);
});
res.end('Success');
```

Comment: Getting closer! Data is being input into the SQL table, however both values are "undefined".  This is what my SQL query looks like:  `request.query("insert into persons (FirstName, LastName) values ('" + firstName + "', '" + lastName + "')");`  Any ideas where I might be screwing up?  Thanks

Comment: In your react app, change `{ method: 'POST', data: { FirstName: self.refs.FirstName, LastName: self.refs.LastName }}` to  `{ method: 'POST', body: { FirstName: self.refs.FirstName, LastName: self.refs.LastName }}`. You may also need to stringify the object in the body (just wrap the body value with `JSON.stringify({/*body object*/})`.

Comment: Thanks, should i JSON.stringify in the react app?  Which part of the code should I put that in?

Comment: You may need to do it with the body as part of your post request. So as an example of the second argument passed to fetch: `{ method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify({ FirstName: self.refs.FirstName, LastName: self.refs.LastName })}`. If you made the changes that seanulus suggested, replace the 'self.refs.x' with `this.state.x`.

Comment: I think the `req.body` you're sending has capitalized values too. So  `const { firstName, lastName } = req.body` should be `const { FirstName,LastName } = req.body`

Comment: Thanks guys - changed the letters so FirstName and LastaName are capitalized.  Also wrapped the body with JSON.stringify.  When I did that I get an error "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".  I'll mess around with it tomorrow and see if I can't fix it.  THanks for the help and let me know if you have any more ideas

Comment: I realized that the problem may be that you're forgetting to add the headers to your request. Try adding this as the second argument to fetch: `method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
              FirstName: self.refs.FirstName,
              LastName: self.refs.LastName
            }), headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
          }`. And as seanulus pointed out, make sure that the names/cases of your variables match between your react app and your express app.